# Faster alternative to `repmat` and `permute` in 3d matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, performance, matrix

I'm running the following code

```
a = normrnd(0,1,5000, 300);
b = normrnd(0, 1, 5000, 50);
tic
 xp = repmat(a,1,1,50) .* permute(repmat(b, 1,1, 300), [1 3 2]);
toc
```

which outputs

```
Elapsed time is 0.425773 seconds.
```

Apparently the vast majority of execution time is spent on the `repmat` and `permute` part. I thought some alternative implementation with `bsxfun` might help to speed it up quite a bit, but I don't see exactly how. Is there any better way of dealing with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce running time if instead of `repmat` you use singleton expansion, either [implicit](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) (requires Matlab R2016b or newer):

```
xp = a .* permute(b, [1 3 2]);
```

or explicit with [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
xp = bsxfun(@times, a , permute(b, [1 3 2]));
```

Results on my machine, using [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) (which is more accurate than `tic`, `toc`):

```
>> a = normrnd(0,1,5000, 300);
>> b = normrnd(0, 1, 5000, 50);
>> timeit(@() repmat(a,1,1,50) .* permute(repmat(b, 1, 1, 300), [1 3 2]))
ans =
   0.706580436900000
>> timeit(@() a .* permute(b, [1 3 2]))
ans =
   0.167270436900000
>> timeit(@() bsxfun(@times, a , permute(b, [1 3 2])))
ans =
   0.161594036900000
```

The likely explanation of these reduced times is that in the `repmat` approach the extended arrays are explicitly constructed, which requires memory allocation.